# What are the dangers of having a database with over a million tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Can a MySql database handle over a million tables (mostly small, less than 10 rows)? I started a project that will store lots of literature, each sentence being stored in a different table consisting of about 2-10 rows. Here are some of my concerns.

1. Will performing SELECT and INSERT queries in this database be slowed down? How much?
2. Do website hosting services set a limit on the number of tables in a database? Or is there a universal limit for everyone?
3. Anything else I should be concerned about?

I hope this is the right place to ask this question. Thanks.

edited:

I knew the "why" questions would come! I am crowd-sourcing translation work. My current plan is to have each sentence of a document its own table. Each row of the table will have the data for each suggested translation. For example:
table "documents" will have a list of the documents being worked on.
table "document_1" will be the text of one document, each row conaining one sentence.
table "document_1_1" will contain each suggested translation.

I am open to hearing a better plan :)

Comment: *each sentence being stored in a different table...* is not a good idea.

Comment: What Rajdeep said. But staying on subject, it should be fine. 1kk rows shouldn't impact performance at all.

Comment: Without knowing your application, something tells me that you need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: That is not how a relational database is supposed to be designed and sounds like a doorway into a future of despair and horrors.

Comment: @Andrew - He's talking about 1kk tables, not rows. :o

Comment: Oh god, I completely misread the question in that case. Yes that's not a very good idea to say the least. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Could you expand on your question to outline *why* you would want such a database structure?

Comment: Practically, if you use InnoDB, you can have up to 4 billion tables. That is if  the underlying file system allowes it. Every table consists of 1-3 files so...  1M tables would be 1-3M files in one folder. That will have a huge impact on performance.

Comment: You never would be able to manage millions of tables. There is no need for that.

Comment: I knew the "why" questions would come! I am crowd-sourcing translation work. My current plan is to have each sentence of a document its own table. Each row of the table will have the data for each suggested translation. For example: table "documents" will have a list of the documents being worked on. table "document_1" will be the text of the document, each row conaining one sentence. table "document_1_1" will contain each suggested translation. I am open to hearing a better plan :)

Comment: @billyhafiz - you can have one table for sentences; and one table for translations - the translation table needs a foreign key referring to the primary key of the sentence table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, mysql does not have a limit to number of tables in a database.
Although, obviously, you will be constrained by how much disk space
you have available.

> Answers:

1. It can be very slow. Slow, that it may start hanging.
2. I have just seen limit on number of databases, which is a marketing tactic. I don't know about the number of tables.
3. It is generally considered a bad practice to have a database schema where the number of tables grows over time. Strongly suggest to Redesign the  database.

Instead of hundreds of thousands of tables, make just one table. Add a column containing the text that you were using to name your tables.

> From what I understood, you can have a table with these four
>   columns:
>
> 1. A primary key - bigint
> 2. Name - text size 100, this can be your current table name (document name)
> 3. Description - max text size, the data you have in table goes in this column (document text)
> 4. Translation - max text size, the translation goes in this column (translated text)
>
> Your column two above can be non-unique and repeat as per the number
>   of rows in the table (2-10 times).

For more help and advice please post your questions, I know many people here are curious to know what you are cooking here.

PS. Not a mysql person, I am sure you know what datatypes to use

Comment: Thanks for answering the questions _I_ asked, rather than asking your own question and answering it instead!

Comment: Update: I had a friend suggest OneToMany mapping, and I only need 3-4 tables to include everything: all the literature, all the sentences, all the translations, and all the comments. Users no longer create tables but just add rows to the existing tables. I think this is what @andrewsi was suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an comment, here's some facts:
With InnoDB, you can theoretically have up to 4 billion tables.

MySQL store every database in it's own folder, where every table will consist of 1-3 files. This means that for for 1 million tables, you will have a folder with 1-3 million files. Many file systems have limits on how many files you can have in one folder so depending on the files system, you might already be limited.

When I tested having only one empty table in a MySQL database, I got two files for that table. Together they were around 104 Kb in size. So for 1 million empty tables that would be a little more than 100 Gb of storage on the server.

I wouldn't recommend this architecture from both a performance and maintainability perspective.